# How to change back to LXDE from XFCE?

Tags: lxde, pixel, desktop

I installed XFCE, but I really need to change back to LXDE/PIXEL.
How do I change back to PIXEL/LXDE?

--LEHA

Comment: Why don't you just restore from your backup?

Comment: Sorry, I really need to switch back to lxde without flashing the card.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the RpiOS [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager#Implementations) (DM) -- this is what provides the graphical login -- but usually they have some kind of discrete menu button on the login page with which you can select an alternate DE to log into.  If not, pretty sure the DM is **lightdm**, which currently seems to have very poor to non-existent online docs, but the [github site](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm) has some in XML/docbook format :/